# Countability of a set: only 2 options?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

So I know sets can be countable (bijection between set and $\mathbb{N}$, finite) or uncountable. Is there another option or are all sets either or?

Comment: Well, your question is like: "all the living beings on this planet are humans or non-humans. Is there any other option?" The third excluded principle makes that clear.

Comment: If you believe in classical logic (tertium non datur), then all sets are either or. But there are of course different orders of uncountability.

Comment: There are uncountable sets of different sizes, but yes, every set is either countable or uncountable, and none is both. It’s no different from saying that every set either has at most $10$ elements or has more than $10$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Once you accept the law of excluded middle, and $\varphi$ is a property which you can express (e.g. countability) every element in the universe either satisfies $\varphi$ or its negation.

Recall the definitions:

1. $A$ is countable if there is an injection from $A$ into $\Bbb N$.
2. $A$ is uncountable if it is not countable.

So every set $A$ either satisfies the property "being countable", in which case it is countable; or it doesn't in which case... it is uncountable.

Of course, much like "finite" doesn't tell you much about the cardinality of a set, just that it is finite, being uncountable doesn't tell you much about the cardinality of a set except that it is not countable. There are many uncountable sets of different cardinalities, but they are all uncountable nonetheless (much like there are many irrational numbers with varying algebraic and algebraic-like properties, but they are all irrational numbers nonetheless).

Comment: I understand that, logically, Dedekind-finite infinite sets are uncountable, but I can't help feeling that they are unworthy of the name. By the way, if you use the word "denumerable" to mean "equipollent to $\mathbb N$", as some people do, then by the same logic, finite sets should be nondenumerable. But I don't think anyone actually uses "nondenumerable" to mean "finite or uncountable".

Comment: bof, first of all if you learn more about infinite Dedekind-finite you will learn that they deserve every bit of the name "uncountable". I also never heard anyone uses "non-denumerable". Ever.

Answer (score 0):

There are varying degrees of uncountability, but since "uncountable" means "not countable," a set is either countable or not, hence either countable or uncountable.

As for the varying degrees, in general $2^A$, the set of all subsets of a set $A$, has a different cardinality than does $A$. So $U = 2^\mathbb N$ is bigger than $\mathbb N$, and $2^U$ is even bigger than $U$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) says that the cardinality of the power set $2^A$ (the power set is the set of all subsets of a set) of $A$ is larger than the cardinality of $A$. This means that $2^{\Bbb{R}}$ has a larger cardinality than $\Bbb{R}$. But if you take the definition of uncountable to be anything which isn't finite and can't be put into bijection with $\Bbb{N}$ then yes, everything is either at most countable or uncountable. There are an infinite number of different infinite cardinalities though.

We can know surprisingly little about these cardinalities beyond this. It turns out that the [continuum hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), which states there are no sets with cardinality between that of the intergers and that of the real numbers (i.e. the continuum) cannot be proven or disproven using ZFC, which is the "standard model" of mathematics.

It can be proven if you assume the Axiom of Choice that the cardinality of the integers is the smallest non-finite cardinal. This is called $\aleph_0$.

It also turns out that if you assume the Axiom of Choice, you know that there is  a smallest cardinality, or cardinal number, which is larger than any given one. The smallest one larger than $\aleph_n$ is called $\aleph_{n+1}$ and then you have a linear ordering on all cardinals. Without AC things are more challenging.

Comment: I think that this answer can be very confusing to someone not already possessing enough knowledge about set theory. (Also since you mention the axiom of choice, the result about $\aleph_0$ being the smallest infinite cardinal also requires some choice.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I imagine if one knows the proof that the real numbers are uncountable they could probably understand the statement of Cantor's theorem and know about AC. My primary purpose was to link to the wikipedia articles. I added the part about requiring choice for $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Sam, in my universities there is no introductory course to set theory, and one learns these things in some calculus related course. They don't learn Cantor's theorem, just the diagonal argument; they don't learn about the axiom of choice either. In other places, they don't really teach about the axiom of choice nor $\aleph$ numbers in undergrad set theory courses. Just today I had lunch with three professors (one senior, and two starting ones - both of them from visiting) and we had a few words about undergrad set theory being naive and all that.